# Mysql right to use myisam for this table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

ID (auto increment, int), pass (char(5)), email (varchar(80))

This is set to be used for:

Adding rows for each new user (high load).

Updating their account to add an email address.

If users forget ID, they can enter their email address and it will return the ID)

There are very very few deletes (once a week in bulk usually).  The ratio is about 70% inserts, 25% email updates, 5% search by email address.

Whats structure would you say is best for this?

ID is going to be a primary key, should I set email as a key too?

Comment: Are you asking what storage engine to use or table structure to use?

Comment: I think the question is whether to index by email, am I right?

Comment: Its a bit of everything.  Storage engine, and what to set as indexes is dependant on this too I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I'd go with InnoDB so that you get row-level locking.  If "email" appears in a WHERE clause it should minimally be indexed for performance reasons.

Comment: hmmm... yeah, Dagon makes a point... whether or not to index email depends on frequency of lost password query I suppose.  I'd probably index it personally.

Comment: How do I set it to "minimally index"?  Also, what is the cost of indexing vs. not indexing?

Comment: cost depends on frequency of reads versus writes.  specific cost you can test on your specific setup.  but in all cases indexes will add overhead to inserts while cutting down on read times.  when i said "minimally be indexed" i wasn't referring to a special sort of index.  correctly indexing fields in a database is a very large topic.  there's a pretty good mysql performance book: http://amzn.to/gxyQLH.

Answer (score 0):

5 char password is very low, it should be hashed and salted so probably end up 32 chars
an email can be longer than 80 char's.

Indexing email would speed up searches by email but it sounds like it wont happen enough to make much difference

Comment: @david19801 - no such thing as "minimally index" it either is or is not indexed, although there are index types. The only cost is a little space, but an index can slow down a query- big beginner mistake is indexing everything. phpmyadmin, or what ever you use will show you how much space the index is taking.